# PYTEST deleted EVERYTHING in my documents folder. Can I recover it?

Tags: pytest

I was following a tutorial in the pytest documentation for creating temporary directories, https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/tmpdir.html and when I executed the following code, the contents of my entire `documents` folder was deleted.

```
import pytest
import os

@pytest.fixture()
def tmdirmak(tmpdir_factory):
    f = tmpdir_factory.mktemp("data")
    return f

def test_temp(tmp_path):
    d = tmp_path / "sub1"
    d.mkdir()
    p = d / "tem.txt"
    p.write_text("hello")
    assert p.read_text() == "hello"

    os.system("ls")
```

This file was saved in my `documents` folder and this is where I ran the command `pytest --basetemp=. -s test_paths.py`  which accounting to the documentation is how you change where the temporary directory is made. I did not want the temporary directory to be made in /tmp but rather I wanted it created in the same directory that my code lives. When I ran this I got the following pytest output

```
test_paths.py E

================================================= ERRORS ==================================================
_______________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_temp _______________________________________

path = '/Users/matthewclark/Documents', ignore_errors = False
onerror = functools.partial(<function on_rm_rf_error at 0x7fe29a845dd0>, start_path=PosixPath('/Users/matthewclark/Documents'))

    def rmtree(path, ignore_errors=False, onerror=None):
        """Recursively delete a directory tree.
    
        If ignore_errors is set, errors are ignored; otherwise, if onerror
        is set, it is called to handle the error with arguments (func,
        path, exc_info) where func is platform and implementation dependent;
        path is the argument to that function that caused it to fail; and
        exc_info is a tuple returned by sys.exc_info().  If ignore_errors
        is false and onerror is None, an exception is raised.
    
        """
        if ignore_errors:
            def onerror(*args):
                pass
        elif onerror is None:
            def onerror(*args):
                raise
        if _use_fd_functions:
            # While the unsafe rmtree works fine on bytes, the fd based does not.
            if isinstance(path, bytes):
                path = os.fsdecode(path)
            # Note: To guard against symlink races, we use the standard
            # lstat()/open()/fstat() trick.
            try:
                orig_st = os.lstat(path)
            except Exception:
                onerror(os.lstat, path, sys.exc_info())
                return
            try:
                fd = os.open(path, os.O_RDONLY)
            except Exception:
                onerror(os.lstat, path, sys.exc_info())
                return
            try:
                if os.path.samestat(orig_st, os.fstat(fd)):
                    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
                    try:
>                       os.rmdir(path)
E                       PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/matthewclark/Documents'

../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/shutil.py:496: PermissionError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

path = '/Users/matthewclark/Documents', ignore_errors = False
onerror = functools.partial(<function on_rm_rf_error at 0x7fe29a845dd0>, start_path=PosixPath('/Users/matthewclark/Documents'))

    def rmtree(path, ignore_errors=False, onerror=None):
        """Recursively delete a directory tree.
    
        If ignore_errors is set, errors are ignored; otherwise, if onerror
        is set, it is called to handle the error with arguments (func,
        path, exc_info) where func is platform and implementation dependent;
        path is the argument to that function that caused it to fail; and
        exc_info is a tuple returned by sys.exc_info().  If ignore_errors
        is false and onerror is None, an exception is raised.
    
        """
        if ignore_errors:
            def onerror(*args):
                pass
        elif onerror is None:
            def onerror(*args):
                raise
        if _use_fd_functions:
            # While the unsafe rmtree works fine on bytes, the fd based does not.
            if isinstance(path, bytes):
                path = os.fsdecode(path)
            # Note: To guard against symlink races, we use the standard
            # lstat()/open()/fstat() trick.
            try:
                orig_st = os.lstat(path)
            except Exception:
                onerror(os.lstat, path, sys.exc_info())
                return
            try:
                fd = os.open(path, os.O_RDONLY)
            except Exception:
                onerror(os.lstat, path, sys.exc_info())
                return
            try:
                if os.path.samestat(orig_st, os.fstat(fd)):
                    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
                    try:
                        os.rmdir(path)
                    except OSError:
>                       onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
E                       PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/matthewclark/Documents'

../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/shutil.py:498: PermissionError
============================================ 1 error in 0.21s =============================================
```

I think returned to find all my folders and documents in my `documents` directory to be deleted! I suspect since pytest normally thinks it is in /tmp it just clears out all the stuff in that folder when it is done, including the things it didn't create. If this is true, this is a horrible bug. What's strange is I received these permission errors yet my contents were deleted anyway.

Comment: Bad luck l would say. This is the intended behavior - the tempdir is deleted after the test using `rmtree`. The permissions error came from trying to delete the documents folder itself, where the test was executing. BTW, your fixture is not used anywhere, the problem is only related to the test itself.

Comment: _Can I recover it?_ Yes, if you are using Time Machine, it's very easy - just find the latest snapshot still containing the files, copy them from the snapshot. If not, it's the perfect time to start using it.